# Develop outlook add-in compatible with multiple versions

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I created a VSTO outlook add-in under the outlook 2010. But seems it doesn't work when it was deployed to outlook 2007. The inefficient way to solve the problem is compiling again under the outlook 2007.Is there any better way to make it work in both versions? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. What I have done is testing at the start of the addin (starup function) wether the version of outlook is 14 (for 2010) or not. But I had to install Office 2007 and compile again in an outlook 2007 project to see the result. The program is functional but I still have some errors.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to create one VSTO Outlook Add-in as per this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx)

Basically the new embedded interop types feature in Visual Studio 2010 help the Add-in to resolve the PIAs at run time. The only issue is that you need to code with the lower denominator (2007) or check the Outlook version in code and enable the 2010 required features.

Alternative: You may consider the use of a third-party-tool (www.add-in-express.com), this tool allows the creation of version-independent add-ins.