# not loaded : a run-time error occurred during the loading of the com add in outlook 2013

Tags: wpf, outlook-addin

I have a WPF outlook add-in which is developed in Visual Studio 2008 with C#. It is working fine with Microsoft outlook 2003, 2007 & 2010. But when I installed it in outlook 2013, its not getting activated. When I try to activate it , the following exception is seen.

**not loaded : a runtime error occurred during the loading of the com add in outlook 2013**

If you have come across such a situation and found a solution, Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking of VSTO addin, it depends on what version of office com libraries you refer in the project. You may have to go through the below link:
[Develop outlook add-in compatible with multiple versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929865/develop-outlook-add-in-compatible-with-multiple-versions)

Alternatively, you can use add in express toolkit to build one Addin targeting multiple MS office versions.
https://www.add-in-express.com/